# How could I decide how much data to load in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have a database with nodes that points to other nodes in parent children relationship and a lookup table to translate between web addresses and nodes.

I need to get information about the node and it's parents and children but each time I fetch a node through the lookup table it only loads the data related to that node (name etc.) is there any way of go past this lazy loading and fetch more data?

My data structures:

```
NodeLookup: 
    long id;   
    String url;  
    Node node;  

Node:  
    long id;  
    String name;  
    List<Node> parents; //@ManyToMany  
    List<Node> childrens; //@ManyToMany
```

Now I solve it by fetching a node through the NodeLookup table and use the node's id to fetch the node for real but that seems like a waste of resources.

(I'm using the play framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JPA use lazy load for relations. If you want load the relations when you load the node, you must use eager load :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
List<Node> parents;

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER
List<Node> childrens;
```

Comment: Yeah that seams to be working, thanks. But will that mean that it will load all children and the children's children and so on? Is there any way limit how deep that gets loaded?

Comment: i think, you must remove eager load and just call size() method on childrens and parents in your controller or model, when you want load them

Comment: I tried that earlier but it didn't seemed to work.. Will give it another try.